# リスト型は入れ子に出来ても、集合型は入れ子に出来ない？

Tags: python3

リスト型が入れ子に出来たので、集合型でも試してみたのですが

```
data = set([9,[8,7],6,6,5])
print(data) 
print(type(data))
```

下記エラーが表示されました

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

・ハッシュ化できない？
・リストを集合型のキーとして使用している？？
・どういう意味ですか？

---

**追記分。下記理解で合っているでしょうか？**
・集合型には、set, frozensetがある
・setは、ミュータブルで可変なので、要素のハッシュ値が確定できない。集合の要素に出来ない、入れ子に出来ない
・frozensetは、イミュータブルなので、要素のハッシュ値が確定できる。集合の要素に出来る、入れ子に出来る
・集合型で入れ子が出来る要件は、入れ子にされる側が不変(要素のハッシュ値が確定できるfrozenset)な場合だけ

Comment: その理解であっていると思います。イミュータブルなtupleならできますね。`data = set([9,(8,7),6,6,5])`

Comment: set()の引数は、リスト型を指定しているわけではなく、たまたま[,]を指定しているだけということでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、コメントを編集したのですが、set()はイテレーション可能なオブジェクトでかつ要素のハッシュ値が確定できるものであることが必要です。なので(8,7)はOKだけど[8,7]はダメということです。

Comment: `set`が可変だからですよ。入れ子にされるほうの集合は`frozenset`を使ってください

Comment: [4. Built-in Types — Python 3.6.4 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set)から、「The elements of a set must be hashable.」 `[].__hash__()` と `().__hash__()` の違いなど。

Comment: 追記分、それで合ってますよ。正確にはイミュータブルだからハッシュ値が確定できるというよりはPythonでHashable（ハッシュ可能）型として規定される特殊メソッド`__hash__()`の適切な実装があるからですね。ちなみに、集合の中にリストを入れたいときはリストの代わりにタプルを入れたりします（最初のコメでKenjiさんが質問のコードをそのまま汲み取って言ってくれてるのがコレ）

Comment: 「正確には」の件、参考になりました。また「Kenji‌​さん」の件も参考になりました。tuple自体が入れ子に出来ることは知っていたのですが、ここでは集合型の入れ子の側でtupleを使用していたのですね。「イミュータブルなtupleならできますね」の意味がようやく分かりました

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`set` や `list` は可変なのでハッシュ可能じゃありません。つまり、集合の要素できません。

```
data = set([9,[8,7],6,6,5])
```

上記の `[8,7]` はリストであり、集合の入れ子ではなく、集合の要素にリストを指定してます。あなたの狙いでは、

```
data = set([9,set([8,7]),6,6,5])
```

のつもりではないでしょうか？

ただし、`set` も可変なので集合の要素にできず、入れ子にできません。入れ子にされる側には不変の集合 `frozenset` を使う必要があります。

```
data = {9, frozenset([8, 7]), 6, 6, 5}
print(data)
print(type(data))
# {9, 5, frozenset({8, 7}), 6}
# <class 'set'>
```

Comment: 「集合の要素にリストを指定している件」納得しました。また、私の狙いを汲み取っていただき、ありがとうございます。frozensetを今回初めて知ったのですが、疑問に思った点を本文に追記しました